# Using NetBeans for PHP, outputting XML rather than HTML, Netbeans sees errors

Tags: php, xml, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans to develop a PHP app, and it works just fine for any PHP pages which output HTML.

However, some of my PHP scripts output XML and (more specifically) KML.  NetBeans doesn't seem to understand this, and I get a load of "invalid content" errors in the IDE, as it expects me to be outputting proper HTML code.

Is there some way to set NetBeans to accept any XML, rather than only HTML?

Comment: where do you want to view this? in the editor? you could then right-click it + click 'open as ...' -> xml

Comment: Even though it has PHP code in it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click one of the errors, there is an option to disable the HTML error checking for that particular file.